# Easy Limit not working that should be 0?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to compute the following limit, which, tell me if I am wrong, should be 0 for beta->Infinity when z

```
 k[z_, beta_] = (Sinh[(1 - I)*Sqrt[beta/2]* z] - 
 2 z Sinh[((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]])/((1 - I)*
  Sqrt[beta/2] Cosh[((1 - I)/2)* Sqrt[beta/2]] - 
 2 Sinh[((1 - I)/2) Sqrt[beta/2]]);
 Limit[k[z, beta], beta -> Infinity]
```

How come I am not getting any output from Mathematica? 
With regard to the limit going to 0, please look at the following plot:

```
 Manipulate[Plot[Abs[k[z, beta]], {z, -1/2, 1/2}], {beta, 1, 10000000}]
```

Can we state the limit is 0 as the order of magnitude is decreasing?

Comment: Try this and see what happens `k[z, beta] /. beta -> Infinity`

Comment: If I specify a value for `z` say `1` the `Limit` is `ComplexInfinity`

Answer (score 3):

The limit is parameter dependent. Large `z` case:

```
Limit[k[z, beta], beta -> Infinity, Assumptions -> z > 1/2]

(* Out[117]= ComplexInfinity *)
```

Small `z` case:

```
Limit[k[z, beta], beta -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < z < 1/2]

(* Out[120]= 0 *)
```

Comment: does it work also for `-1/2<z<0`?

Comment: I actually ran your second limit and Mathematica didn't return any output and doesn't seem to work. Can it depend on the version? Im using 10.4.1.0 Student Edition

Comment: Yes, it might depend on version. It also could depend on speed of  hardware and software, since some subcomputations have to be time constrained (so `Limit` will not hang). As for -1/2<z<0, I just tried it: `In[3]:= Limit[k[z, beta], beta -> Infinity, Assumptions ->-1/2<z<0]                                       

Out[3]= 0`

Comment: is there a way to remove the time constraint and try to get your same result for the one that I am not getting with my software/hardware?

Comment: No way to remove time constraints, that's all in internal code.  And if the result depends on version then removing them would not change things.

Comment: which version did you use?

Comment: Mathematica 11.1

Answer (score 2):

No, the limit is in general not zero:

```
<< NumericalCalculus`
Plot[ReIm@NLimit[k[z,beta], beta->Infinity, Terms->15], {z, -.8, .8},  PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: what about `Manipulate[Plot[Abs[k[z, beta]], {z, -1/2, 1/2}], {beta, 1, 10000000}]`? can we say the limit is 0 in z in the range of (-1/2,1/2)?

Answer (score 1):

It actually appears to be zero for, `Abs[z]<1/2` :

```
f[z_] := Limit[k[z, beta] , beta -> Infinity]
{#, f[#]} & /@ Range[-1, 1, 1/10]
```

> {{-1, ComplexInfinity}, {-(9/10), ComplexInfinity}, {-(4/5), 
>     ComplexInfinity}, {-(7/10), ComplexInfinity}, {-(3/5), 
>     ComplexInfinity}, {-(1/2), 0}, {-(2/5), 0}, {-(3/10), 0}, {-(1/5), 
>     0}, {-(1/10), 0}, {0, 0}, {1/10, 0}, {1/5, 0}, {3/10, 0}, {2/5, 
>     0}, {1/2, 0}, {3/5, ComplexInfinity}, {7/10, ComplexInfinity}, {4/5,
>      ComplexInfinity}, {9/10, ComplexInfinity}, {1, ComplexInfinity}}

It is zero for some complex z as well. Its not clear if the bound is `Abs[z]<1/2` though.

This does not work BTW:

```
 Limit[k[z, beta] , beta -> Infinity, 
     Assumptions -> {Element[z, Reals], -1/2 < z < 1/2}]
```

Comment: I agree with the fact that the limit is 0, which is the result that I expected. May I ask you why we cannot get a global result, rather than computing it discretely as you do? I just ran your last line but Mathematica didn't return an outoput but the input itself. Isn't `Assumptions` a function for `Refine`, `Integrate` and `Simplify`? Why are you using it here?

Comment: I don't know. You may want to un-accept this. Maybe someone else will know a trick to get a general result.

Answer (score 1):

You can proof the result, -1/2<=z<=1/2, with a few transformations and then a series-expansion like that

```
 k[z_, ceta_] = (Sinh[(1 - I)*Sqrt[beta/2]*z] - 
     2 z Sinh[((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]])/((1 - I)*
     Sqrt[beta/2] Cosh[((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]] - 
     2 Sinh[((1 - I)/2) Sqrt[beta/2]]) //. Sqrt[beta/2] -> ceta
```

Terms with Exp[-ceta/2] disapear,since ceta -> Infinity

```
 k1[z_, ceta_] = (k[z, ceta] // TrigExpand // Together // 
    TrigToExp) /. E^(-ceta/2) -> 0 // Simplify
```

Do ComplexExpand of the real part. (You get exactly the same for the imaginary part.)

```
 se = Simplify[
      ComplexExpand[Re[k1[z, ceta]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], 
         Assumptions -> {z \[Element] Reals, ceta \[Element] Reals}] // 
         Expand
```

Do the series expansion and set Sin, Cos to Interval[{-1,1}]

```
 se2 = Series[se, {ceta, \[Infinity], 1}] // Normal // Expand

 se3 = (se2) /. Cos[_] -> Interval[{-1, 1}] /. 
 Sin[_] -> Interval[{-1, 1}] // FullSimplify // Factor // Expand

 (*    -(z/ceta) + (E^(-ceta (1/2 + z)) Interval[{-1, 1}])/ceta + (
      E^(2 ceta z - ceta (1/2 + z)) Interval[{-1, 1}])/ceta     *)
```

Here you see, with Limit ceta->Infinity the exponetial terms either go to 0 or they explode, depending on z

Limit goes to 0, if

```
 Reduce[-1/2 - z <= 0, z]

 (*   z >= -(1/2)   *)
```

and

```
 Reduce[2 z - (1/2 + z) <= 0, z]

 (*     z <= 1/2    *)
```

Comment: This is pretty much what `Limit` does.

Comment: Not exactly. With Limit, you have to guess the convergence limits with the help of some other information. Here you get them directly and proofed to be the only one.